likert plot with categories and one factor in ggplot2 in R
I have a dataframe in R that has two columns: column A with likert values, and var column with values NO and YES. How can I use gglikert() with grouping category?
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggstats)

set.seed(123)
likert_levels <- c(
  "1" = "Very  Dissatisfied",
  "2" = "Dissatisfied",
  "3" = "Neutral",
  "4" = "Satisfied",
  "5" = "Very  Satisfied")

df = data.frame(
  var = sample(c("NO","YES"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  A = sample(likert_levels, 50, replace = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(across(everything(),as.factor))%>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(across(-var, ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))

df


gglikert(df, A, facet_rows = vars(var)) ?

This question seems similar to your previous one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78922118/gglikert-in-r-with-grouping-facets
